# Django drf-spectacular How to split api descriptions for public and private use?

Tags: django, drf-spectacular

I want to make 2 different documentations. One is for public with few api methods and no authz. Another one is for private usage with all api methods and only for authorized users.

Comment: @rayn-m why did you delete my answer?

Answer (score 2):

2 choices:

1. If you use the build-in Swagger and the user visiting the UI is somehow auth'ed, you can use the setting `'SERVE_PUBLIC': False`. It will filter the schema based on the permissions the requesting user has access to. Spectacular will attempt to use the (first) credentials provided by the `Authorize` button and fetch the schema with that. If your auth method differs from DRF's setting `AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`, you might also need to set spectacular's `SERVE_AUTHENTICATION` accordingly.
2. Or actually create 2(+2) endpoints that serve distinct schemas and potentially customize them

```py
# public part
path('api/schema-public/', SpectacularAPIView.as_view(
    custom_settings={
        'SERVE_URLCONF': [...]  # urlpatterns with the public endpoint list
    },
), name='schema-public'),
path('api/schema/swagger-ui-public/', SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(url_name='schema-public')),

# private part
path('api/schema-private/', SpectacularAPIView.as_view(
    # settings deviating from global spectacular settings go here.
    custom_settings={
        'TITLE': 'Private API',
        'SERVE_URLCONF': [...]  # urlpatterns with the private endpoint list
        ...
    },
    # not required but might want to also protect if it is sensitive
    authentication_classes=[...],
    permission_classes=[...],
), name='schema-private'),
path('api/schema/swagger-ui-private/', SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(url_name='schema-private')),
```

Comment: I receive "TypeError: SpectacularSwaggerView() received an invalid keyword 'custom_settings'. as_view only accepts arguments that are already attributes of the class."

Comment: oh sry, that was a copy&paste error. the private part was correct. The `custom_settings` parameter belongs into `SpectacularAPIView`

Answer (score 1):

In my case Insa's second choice lead to `SERVE_URLCONF not allowed in custom_settings. use dedicated parameter instead.` error (drf-spectacular: 0.24.0)
So I separated public_urlpatterns in separated file named `public_urls.py` with urlpatterns list, then created new

```
path(..., SpectacularAPIView.as_view(urlconf=["app_name.public_urls"], ...)
```

Comment: Got `TypeError: SpectacularSwaggerView() received an invalid keyword 'urlconf'. as_view only accepts arguments that are already attributes of the class.`

Comment: wihch drf-spectacular version do you use?